# How can I get my <p> elements to be vertically centered along side <input> and <textarea> fields?

Tags: html, css, center, vertical-alignment

I can't get the `p`, `input` and `textarea` elements all be centered with in a `li` elements in a user settings area I am working on right now. Right now only the `input` and `textarea` elements are being properly centered with in the `li` elements while the `p` elements are positioned right at the top. I have tried to apply

`vertical-align: middle`

to the `li` element but it failed.

My [example code link is here at JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/erefo/3/edit)

To help guide you while looking at my example, each element's background color is as follows:

- `p` = red
- `li` = cyan
- `input` & `textarea` = white

How can I get the `p`, `input` and `textarea` elements all be centered with in a `li` elements?

Comment: Replace the `p` elements with `label` elements (since your input labels are labels and are not paragraphs). Then you won't have the problem of dealing with paragraphs and all their associated margins and blockness. Don't forget the `for` attribute.

Comment: @David... I don't think that would work for the text area. But +1 b/c it works with the `<input>` elements

Comment: @David good idea. thanks. i saw this used on Twitter on their settings>profile page. they use tables to compose their settings page. i wonder if i should do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that sites like Twitter and Facebook create their settings pages with the following HTML elements:

- table
- tbody
- tr
- th
- td
- label

So I decided to follow this standard practice and [this is what I came up with](http://jsbin.com/uhoqo4/5/edit). The CSS styling is not there but you can see that basic solid structure that the `table` element and its child elements provide. Notice how the `table tbody tr th label` names automatically are positioned at the center of their containing table cell. And if I need them to be positioned to the top, bottom or baseline than all I need to do is add `vertical-align` to `label`'s parent element which is `th`.

[This is the result of adding `vertical-align: top;` styling to the `th` element in the same row as the `textarea`.](http://jsbin.com/uhoqo4/6)

And if I want to position the `label` elements horizontally with in the table cell then all I need to do is use the `text-align`selector on the `th` element and presto.

[This is the result of adding `text-align: right;` to the 2nd `th` in the 2nd `tr` and the 3rd and 4th `tr th` elements.](http://jsbin.com/uhoqo4/7)